# PlantUML java automation

Tags: java, maven, automation, plantuml

Currently I am working on a project that should represent all classes via [PlantUML's](https://plantuml.com/). I have heard that this UML could be generated automatically using Maven. But unfortunately all articles and repos are already 6-9 years old and therefore outdated.

Would anyone have a tutorial for me?

Comment: what's wrong with following old articles if they are still valid? This plugin still works: https://github.com/devlauer/plantuml-generator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eg. use https://github.com/devlauer/plantuml-generator

Just copied from the here https://github.com/devlauer/plantuml-generator/blob/master/README.adoc):

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>plantuml-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <groupId>de.elnarion.maven</groupId>
  <version>1.1.2</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
        <id>generate-simple-diagram</id>
        <goals>
            <goal>generate</goal>
        </goals>
        <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
        <configuration>
            <outputFilename>testdiagram1.txt</outputFilename>
            <scanPackages>
                <scanPackage>
                some.package.to.process
                </scanPackage>
            </scanPackages>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```